# Print a header on set page using Abc PDF

Tags: pdf-generation, abcpdf

I have created pdf from HTML page using Abc PDF now my problem is I want to print a table header on next page, but only if table data is display within a another page, if not display header on a different page, any one have idea about how we can do this using Abc pdf.

Answer (score 2):

What you need to do is create the page with some space at the top, then once your document is built in abc PDF loop though the pages and add a header.

The code below is what I use to add a header, the header in this case has three bits a image at the top and two boxes with text in.

Remember the cord in abc pdf are from the bottom right not the top left.

```
private static Doc AddHeader(Doc theDoc, Core.Property propertyDetails)
{
    int theCount = theDoc.PageCount;
    int i = 0;

    //Image header 
    for (i = 1; i <= theCount; i++)
    {
        theDoc.Rect.Width = 590;
        theDoc.Rect.Height = 140;

        theDoc.Rect.Position(0, 712);

        theDoc.PageNumber = i;

        //Check Which office to use. 
        string imagefilePath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("/images/pdf/pdf-header.png");


        Bitmap myBmp = (Bitmap)Bitmap.FromFile(imagefilePath);

        theDoc.AddImage(myBmp);
    }

    //page header boxes. 
    //Grey header box 
    theDoc.Rect.String = "20 15 590 50";
    theDoc.Rect.Position(13, 672);
    System.Drawing.Color colour = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#CCCCCC");
    theDoc.Color.Color = colour;
    theDoc.PageNumber = 1;
    theDoc.FillRect();

    theDoc.Rect.String = "20 15 586 50";
    theDoc.Rect.Position(30, 660);
    System.Drawing.Color pageoneText = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#50474A");
    theDoc.Color.Color = pageoneText;
    string thePageFont = "Century Gothic";
    theDoc.Font = theDoc.AddFont(thePageFont);
    theDoc.FontSize = 16;
    theDoc.PageNumber = 1;
    theDoc.AddText("My Text!!!!!");


    theDoc.Rect.String = "20 15 590 50";
    theDoc.Rect.Position(13, 630);
    System.Drawing.Color greyBox = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#468DCB");
    theDoc.Color.Color = greyBox;
    theDoc.PageNumber = 1;
    theDoc.FillRect();

    theDoc.Rect.String = "20 15 586 50";
    theDoc.Rect.Position(30, 620);
    System.Drawing.Color greyText = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#ffffff");
    theDoc.Color.Color = greyText;
    string thePageFontTwo = "Century Gothic";
    theDoc.Font = theDoc.AddFont(thePageFontTwo);
    theDoc.FontSize = 14;
    theDoc.PageNumber = 1;
    theDoc.AddText("This is more text");

    return theDoc;
}
```

Then once the pdf file is created just call

```
var theDoc = new Doc();

/// Your document creation stuff!!!
theDoc = AddHeader(theDoc, propertyDetails);
```